Should questions that are about a specific alternate blockchain be tagged alternative-blockchains?
E.g. should questions about Namecoin all be tagged alternative-blockchains as well?

Yes - that makes sense, and helps people find and distinguish related questions.

I m using namecoin and consider it a serious, long lasting fork, but still the "alternative blockchains" tag seems useful, bitcoin is still the main cryptocurrency, and all the forks, including the excellent namecoin, are still alternatives.

I think the answer to this question will change over time. In my view, it would be useful to tag questions relating to unproven alternative currencies with the tag "alternatives", but a longer lasting currency with a larger team of developers (like namecoin) should really be tagged with its own tag as well and in the long run won't need to be tagged as "alternative". Of course, then the name of the site might be best changed...

I think until Bitcoin becomes less than 80% of the "alternate currencies market" (which may never come, or may take a very long time), Namecoin should still be tagged alternative-blockchains, as well as namecoin.

Agreed... I tried to say that myself with the words "in the long run...". I've reworded it to try to be clearer.

I agree, though for slightly different reasons: I don't care much about the the market share, rather then about the actual currency goal.

I'm torn. I hate the idea that every question tagged Namecoin will have to also be tagged alternative-blockchains. But I hate the idea that people who search for the alternative-blockchains tag won't find questions about Namecoin.
My slight preference is that alternative-blockchains be reserved for questions about alternative blockchains in general. Questions about a specific alternative-blockchain should be tagged with the name of that chain, if such a tag exists.

Another sub-question worth asking - do we even NEED both tags or should we merge Namecoin, IXCoin, I0Coin, SolidCoin etc and just make them aliases of the alternative-blockchains tag?

@DavidPerry I would say no except maybe Namecoin (depending on namecoin question volume).  Looking at how few questions are asked about individual atl-coins I think using alternative-block chain with synonyms for individual chains (to improving searching) is sufficient.

I think the "alternatives" tag is pointless and harmful, and it would be better to have specific tags for each currency.
This is because it encompasses both currencies with a sane goal that make sense, like Namecoin, and stupid currencies with no other reason than to "play" like tenebrix and the like.
I don't think it's fair to put them in the same bag.
