Should we burninate the tag [alternatives]?
The alternatives is to be too broad and unfocussed to be useful. I suggest it's burnination.
Questions tagged with alternatives should be retagged to the following other tags:

altcoin-development: For questions that refer to mucking about in the codebase to create a new altcoin, or for discussion of algorithm tweaks such as different difficulty adjustment algorithms, or reward schedule changes.
altcoin-trade: For questions about trading non-bitcoin assets.
altcoin: Bucket tag for questions about a distinct cryptocurrency that doesn't have its own tag on our site.
More specific tag that fit on a case by case basis: proof-of-stake, reward-schedule, checkpoints, genesis-block, new tag with the specific cryptocurrency's name…


Please give input: Yay or nay? What other tags would be good replacements? Would you like to commit to do a portion of the work?

Also see: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/342/5406, https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/5406, https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/5406, https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513/5406

Yay from me, having both altcoin and alternatives is definitely confusing, and I'll certainly commit to doing a portion of the work.
Unclear what the deciding factor in making a new tag for a specific altcoin is though, we have litecoin, namecoin, ripple/ripple-* and ethereum despite Ethereum having its own SE, we also have nxt, dogecoin, ardor, zcash, peercoin, Monero, dash, quarkcoin, primecoin, rootstock, vertcoin, iota, ........ Is the only requirement for a new tag that there are a few questions using it?

Tags that aren't used by multiple questions disappear by themselves after a while. And if they are being used by multiple questions, they would probably be useful in some fashion.
